# onClick() Not Firing + Unexpected Number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My onClick function is not triggering, and when I trigger it manually through Console, I get the error of: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number**

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;padding:5px;" class="btn btn-default">
<center><b><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true" onClick="like_post(<?php echo $PinnedObj->ID;?>,<?php echo $client->ID;?>)""></i>
```

The JS function:

```
script type="text/javascript" >
function like_post(PID, UID){
    $.ajax({
    url: "like.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'PID': PID, 'UID': UID, 'liked': '1'},                   
    });

    document.getElementById("like_button"+PID).value = parseInt(document.getElementById("like_button"+PID).value,10) + 1;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that's being rendered after the php call?

Comment: No HTML is rendered after the PHP call, the PHP script just updates DB values.

Comment: The posted JS snippet doesn't contain any syntax errors?

Comment: I'm referring to this: `onClick="like_post(<?php echo $PinnedObj->ID;?>,<?php echo $client->ID;?>)""`

Comment: $PinnedObj is just the Database ID for that post, and the client is the user who is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've used "value" of element that has no it. "value" presents only in  elements. You must use the "text" of element to update it.

Second problem is that you summing  empty text of your element with 1. parseInt of undefined (in your case) gives NaN result in sum with "1" gives "NaN".

```
function like_post(pid, uid) {
    var $btn = $('#like_button'+pid);
    $.post("like.php", {"PID": pid, "UID": uid, "liked": "1"}, function(r) {
        $btn.text(parseInt($(btn).text()||0)+1);
    });
}
```

Updated. But prettier would be if "like.php" will return number of likes

```
function like_post(pid, uid) {
    var $btn = $('#like_button'+pid);
    $.post("like.php", {"PID": pid, "UID": uid, "liked": "1"}, function(r) {
        $btn.text(r);
    });
}
```

Comment: Same issue with the number error and nothing happens when the input is clicked.

Comment: Please provide full HTML code. I can't imagine what happend here. And provide JS exception.

Comment: Code is all PHP except the above segments. Keep getting an unexpected number error but that's when I manually trigger the function, onclick doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery with ajax, so you can extend jquery for a add counter function like this.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  add: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
       var element = $(this);
        if ( element .is( "input" ) ) {
           element.val(parseInt((element.val() || 0)) + 1)
        }

       if ( element .is("button") ) {
         element .text(parseInt((element.text() || 0)) + 1)
       }

    });
  }
});
```

and you just can use as

```
    var $btn = $('#like_button'+pid);
$btn.add();
```

check: https://plnkr.co/edit/gist:1986619?p=preview